Proving a set defined in terms of Fourier transform is dense in $L^2$.
I recently came across this claim in one of the papers on Sobolev estimates for Radon transform (see here).

The set $\left\lbrace \| \cdot \|^t \left( 1 + \| \cdot \|^2 \right)^{\frac{s - t}{2}} \hat{f} \Big| f \in \mathcal{S} \left( \mathbb{R}^n \right) \right\rbrace$ is dense in $L^2 \left( \mathbb{R}^n \right)$.

Here, $\mathcal{S} \left( \mathbb{R}^n \right)$ denotes the Schwartz class, and $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$. Intuitively, it is clear, at least when $t$ and $\frac{s - t}{2}$ are positive integers that the claim is true, since then, the collection is simply the collection of Fourier transform of derivatives of Schwartz functions. However, I cannot see why (and how) this is true for general $t, s \in \mathbb{R}$? Any insights into this are appreciated!

Consider the set Schwartz functions such that the support of their Fourier transform does not contain 0, denoted $\mathcal{S}_0$. This is dense in L². By Fourier-Plancherel so is the range of the Fourier transform applied to this space. I claim that the latter space, $\mathcal{F}\mathcal{S}_0$, is contained in your set above for all $s,t$.
